# Select Min or Max record from a table along with the corresponding name field

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, min, sql-limit

Assuming a table `Family` with `Name` and `Age` and records

```
Bob 55
Alice 40
Marky 12
```

If I run

```
Select Name,Min(Age) from Family
```

I get

```
Bob,12
```

I'm trying to ask for the fields from the single record with the lowest age yet I'm simply getting the first record Name and the Age from the record with the lowest value.

How can I use `Min()` to make that request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you want the entire row that has the smallest age. Assuming that you don't care about ties, you can just sort the rows by ascending `age` and retain the first record only:

```
select *
from family
order by age
limit 1
```